# esri arcgis emit click event in 4.x not working

Tags: javascript, angular, esri, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

Has anyone been successful in getting MapView `emit` method to work for click or double click in JS API 4.20?

I use to programmatically fire a click event in 3.x API but I am not having any success in 4.x.